# Time that an application is running

Tags: android

How do I determine how long an application has been running? Is there a broadcast each time an app is launched and shutdown?

I am trying to log the time spent using an application.

Comment: There is no broadcast, but the activity lifecycle methods (e.g. "onResume", "onPause" and "onDestroy") are called whenever the activity starts or stops being active, or is torn down.

Comment: @Shoan pls check my answer

Answer (score 8):

If you are interested in logging your own application's use, you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the start time, and diff it with the value returned when the app is closed.

To get the entire time the app is up, you would want to diff between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` of your foremost Activity class.  For just the time the app is in the foreground, use `onResume()` and `onPause()` in each of your Activity classes and sum the time from each class.

Comment: Is it possible to know how long somebody else's app is running on the phone? Ex: How long is the gmail app running on the phone?

Comment: @Shoan You should post a new question for this - seems like a pretty popular comment.

Comment: @donturner I was only clarifying the intent of the question. Should I rephrase and add this to the question?

Comment: @Shoan Sorry didn't realise you were the OP. This answer doesn't cover other applications and hence doesn't answer fully your original question. I would unaccept it and see if anyone else can answer your question more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

long currentMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
  cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis-info.activeSince);

  Log.i("TAG", String.format("Process %s has been running since: %d ms",info.process,  info.activeSince));
}
```

Logcat:

```
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 26526 ms
TAG: Process com.qualcomm.telephony has been running since: 68521 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 57456 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.music:main has been running since: 26245 ms
TAG: Process com.android.phone has been running since: 29421 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 52141 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 28602 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.actions has been running since: 74371 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 59166 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.slpc has been running since: 25483 ms
TAG: Process com.android.systemui has been running since: 30142 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 22187 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 28603 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 31621 ms
TAG: Process com.android.systemui has been running since: 27361 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 99678 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.contacts.preloadcontacts has been running since: 45603 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 73457 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 72908 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 37251 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.modemservice has been running since: 37049 ms
TAG: Process .esfm has been running since: 44187 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms has been running since: 14875780 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 94606 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 66227 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 31682 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.modemservice has been running since: 37051 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 32869 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 99691 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 92883 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.cameraone has been running since: 75193 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 57465 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 74054 ms
TAG: Process com.estrongs.android.pop has been running since: 42158 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.system has been running since: 27632 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 26540 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 42027 ms
TAG: Process com.estrongs.android.pop has been running since: 42334 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 99627 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.slpc has been running since: 25575 ms
TAG: Process com.snaptube.premium has been running since: 42312 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 27324 ms
TAG: Process com.estrongs.android.pop has been running since: 10845469 ms
TAG: Process com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel has been running since: 29328 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.config.wifi has been running since: 50966 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms has been running since: 13422977 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.modemservice has been running since: 67877 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 99699 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.system has been running since: 93567 ms
TAG: Process com.android.systemui has been running since: 25460 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.talk has been running since: 14632240 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 27605 ms
TAG: Process com.estrongs.android.pop:ka has been running since: 42437 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 28600 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 40725 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.slpc has been running since: 25556 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 57484 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 35677 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 32947 ms
TAG: Process com.snaptube.premium has been running since: 123580 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 94452 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 28244 ms
TAG: Process com.estrongs.android.pop has been running since: 41920 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.system has been running since: 68805 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 29054 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 33060 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 52153 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 31658 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 28665 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 30579 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.inputmethod.latin has been running since: 27422 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.motocare has been running since: 68330 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 25415 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.ccc has been running since: 59215 ms
TAG: Process android.process.media has been running since: 13885530 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 74301 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.actions has been running since: 73981 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 27310 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.system has been running since: 68538 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor has been running since: 27343 ms
TAG: Process system has been running since: 24919 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.apps.messaging:rcs has been running since: 69945 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 73045 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 28213 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 99706 ms
TAG: Process com.snaptube.premium has been running since: 39033 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 26533 ms
TAG: Process com.android.phone has been running since: 29411 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.process.system has been running since: 94766 ms
TAG: Process com.snaptube.premium has been running since: 14530932 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 36311 ms
TAG: Process com.android.bluetooth has been running since: 26529 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms.persistent has been running since: 24921 ms
TAG: Process com.google.android.gms has been running since: 90390 ms
TAG: Process org.mozilla.firefox has been running since: 80946 ms
TAG: Process com.motorola.actions has been running since: 73986 ms
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: That's only for services, and it doesn't work anymore as it will return only of current app. If the app has no services, it won't return anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
 long millisSinceBoot = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
         System.out.println("00000    "+millisSinceBoot);
         System.out.println("11111    "+values.get(position).activeSince+" "+values.get(position).process);
         long time = ((millisSinceBoot - values.get(position).activeSince)/1000);
         int[] vals = splitToComponentTimes(time);

         String time1 = vals[0]+":"+vals[1]+":"+vals[2];
         time_list.add(time);        
         timer.setText(time1);

         System.out.println("valssssss "+vals[0]+" "+vals[1]);
```