# How to get idle time for android?

Tags: android

How can i get idle time(time for application since started) for running application in android?

I was trying to get the time for all running applications in android

Comment: I think this link is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903650/time-that-an-application-is-running

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find the current time while application going on onPause() and find the current time in onResume(). Find the difference between this two. you will find it.

Comment: Its like timer.I will have list view in which i have to display for all running application. 
e.g:
     Application Name            Idle Time
     gmail                       1:20:90

Comment: i looking for running applications on android device not for single application.