# How to get "How long user has used a certain app" information from android sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am making an android app which will give the details of "How much time user has used a certain app in last 24 hour" information. There will be a detail list of all apps "Used time length".

Is it possible? If yes, How?

If No, why it is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903650/time-that-an-application-is-running

Comment: If you are actually trying to acquire that data for your own app there is already an extensive library that does that and much more. [Check it out.](https://get.fabric.io/#)

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the "Usage Time length" of apps like Facebook, Twitter and Others?  @Goran

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible by implementing **UsageStatsManager** , you can get daily,weekly,monthly and yearly app usage statistics [see UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)

you can do by

**Step : 1** create background service and check current package name with your app package in some repeat time interval.

**Step : 2** save start-end timestamp to local db when current package name change

**Step : 3** to get time - calculate time difference between end-start time

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the "Usage Time length" of apps like Facebook, Twitter and Others?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the app usage related statistics from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html. It contains the methods you require as per your question. You might also want to get more information from [Other statistics you might be interested in](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html) and [Usage based on time intervals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)